# print comma function not working

Tags: python, printing

I put in this code:

```
def game():
down, right = 0, 0
while 1:
    for i in range(down):
        print "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    for j in range(right):
        print "0",
    print "S",
    for j in range(80 - (right + 1)):
        print "0",
    for i in range(38 - (down + 1)):
        print "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    direction = raw_input("Direction?")
    if(direction.upper() == "W"):
        down -= 1
    elif(direction.upper() == "S"):
        down += 1
    elif(direction.upper() == "A"):
        right -= 1
    elif(direction.upper() == "D"):
        right += 1
game()
```

The 'print "S",' is supposed to have a comma at the end, to stop it printing on the next line the next time I call the print function.

The actual thing came up with something like this: (I've chopped some lines containing "000000")

S 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Why do the first zeroes have spaces in-between? There are no spaces in my print function.

Answer (score 3):

```
print "0",
```

Means `print` "0", and `print` a space.

The comma basically causes `print` to output a space instead of a newline. If you want to circumvent this behavior, use `sys.stdout.write()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can set softspace to `False` after every `,`

```
print "S",
sys.stdout.softspace = False
```

but then you might as well use `sys.stdout.write()`